# Style the header in a nextjs. - material ui ReactJs app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have a react/nextjs app and have navigation with Home|account|Jobs.
How do I bold the active link in the navigation? With my code below, the active link is not bold.

I am using the material UI -- Toolbar

Thanks for your help

```
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
...
const StyledLink = withStyles(Link)`
  font-weight: bold;
`;
    class Header extends React.Component {
    ...
      this.state = {
        currentIndex: null
      }
     }
     const menuData = [
       {
         href:"/jobseeker/home",
         tabContent: "Home"
       },
        {
         href:"/jobseeker/account",
         tabContent: "Account"
       },
         ...
    ]
    
    handleSelect = (index) => {
     this.setState({ currentIndex:index });
    }
    render() {
       const { currentIndex } = this.state;
       
        
       {menuData.map((menu,index) => (
         
          <ListItem key={index} onClick={(() => this.handleSelect(index)}>              
           <Link prefetch href={menu.href}>
               <a className={currentIndex === index ? StyledLink:''} >{menu.tabContent}</a>
            </Link>                  
        </ListItem>
    
        ))}
    }}
```

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to get it to work with what I have

Answer (score 0):

You can create `ActiveLink` component following [Official next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function ActiveLink({ children, href }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const style = {
    marginRight: 10,
    color: router.pathname === href ? 'red' : 'black',
  }

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    router.push(href)
  }

  return (
    <a href={href} onClick={handleClick} style={style}>
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}

export default ActiveLink
```